# Vue рендерит все изображения в base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Vue рендерит все в base64. Делаю админку, много чего приходит с сервера.

Хотелось бы что бы на сервере хранился просто путь к изображению и желательно без хеша.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*То что подчеркнуто приходит с сервера*

В гугле написано только как закодировать в base64 но не как раскодировать

**vue.config.js** Пустой

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: '@import "@/admin/assets/style/index.scss";'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Или же лучше хранить изображение все в base64?
В будущем планируется делать что то вроде менеджера изображений как на wordpress и opencart.
Если же в base64 то это же будет легче, я правильно понимаю?

Хотелось бы услышать мнение у более опытных разрабов
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы не добавлялся хэш, вам нужно [игнорировать определенную статику при сборке вэбпаком](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#filenamehashing), что касается изображений, я бы использовал svg или png, в зависимости от того, что размещаете. Вот хорошая статья на тему: [base64 или файл форматы](https://bunnycdn.com/blog/why-optimizing-your-images-with-base64-is-almost-always-a-bad-idea/).