# Как запретить конвертировать локальные картинки в Base64-формат при сборке vue.js-проекта?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli

Пару дней назад все пути картинок поменялись на Base64 формат.

Причину я так и не понял. Уже пару дней бьюсь не могу вернуть прежний формат.

В чем может быть проблема?

Подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1194940/2659) задавал, мне [ответили](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194951/2659) что в Base64 изображения хранить не лучшая идея.

Если надо, вот [Git проекта](https://github.com/Papa2Carlro/admin-panel).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похожая проблема описана на основном SO - почитай: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991089/disable-vue-cli-webpack-encoding-image-base64/51859212)

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/42991089

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь в свой `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
        .rule('images')
        .use('url-loader')
        .loader('url-loader')
        .tap(options => ({ ...options, limit: -1 }))
  },
  ...
}
```

[ответ на большом so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52727581/4496422)

<sub>Проверил на [твоём проекте](https://github.com/Papa2Carlro/admin-panel):</sub>

```
admin-panel $ yarn build
...
admin-panel $ grep -rn base64 dist/ | wc -l
       0
```